# Position button on specific place on scaling image

Tags: javascript, css, image, button, layout

I have an image that scales when changing the screen size. I want to place a button in a specific place on the image (inside the cogwheel) and I want it to stay there.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hmnozjs2/

```
<div class="img">
  <button>
    My button
  </button>
</div>

.img {
  background-image: url("https://knowledge.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/3.15.23-scott-snyder-esg-corporate-innovation-GettyImages-1410816388-900x605.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  width: 90px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 105px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

My original idea was position:absolute. However as I change the width of my screen the button does not stay inside the cogweel at all. I assume I can fix this by flexbox and somehow aligning it...

The bigger issue is when changing the height of the screen, the image then grows or shrinks and I have no idea how I would be able to keep the button in place...

I have looked around but in most places people just want to center a button on an image. That is easy with flexbox, but in my case, the problem is a bit more complicated as the button needs to stay in a very specific place.

I am sure there is a simple solution and this is a common use-case, I am just inexperienced...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/o1u7ag9n/

Comment: I want to put it inside the central cogwheel though and want it to stay there no matter the screen size.

Comment: Don't use a background image as it doesn't scale the same way as the screen positioning. Use an **actual** image and position the element on it using % - See : https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zYELEo

Comment: @Paulie_D if they _want_ that `background-size: cover` behavior, then replacing it with something that behaves completely different, is probably not an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Paulie_D great answer! i think it will be best for the user as he asked for simplest solution and may be cover issue won't affect him. Let wait for his response.

Comment: I am looking for a solution with object-fit:cover or background-size:cover. I don't know how to keep track of a given point in the image while using these properties. Also ideally the button should scale up/down with the image. Do I need to figure out the internals of background-size:cover and write a javascript hack for it?